# how to set select2 value like normal textbox?

Tags: jquery-select2

I wanted to set select2 text box value just like normal textbox being set by jquery e.g `jQuery('#textbox').val()`
how is it possible in select2??

I have tried but not working

```
$("select").val("1").trigger("change");
```

Comment: Do you have an option with a value of `1` ahead of time?

Comment: Also. If you remove Select2, does the value update within your browser as you would normally expect?

Answer (score 0):

select2 does not select value (programatically) like normal select. you have to do it like

```
$("select").val("val","1");
```

Comment: If you are using 4.0.0, the recommended way to set the value is what the OP is currently using. I suspect there is a different issue.